# Trying to merge duplicate cells in a range or rows based off a "Master Key" column

Tags: vba, excel

So here is what I am starting with:

[image]

And here is what I would like it to look like when it is done:

[image]

I think what it needs to do is:

1.) Go through the Route column

2.) Find the duplicate values

3.) Select all the rows between the first duplicate route value and the last

4.) Merge all the duplicate cells in that range

5.) Repeat until you get to the last row of data.

My problems is that I really just don't know enough about vba to do what I want it to do and I haven't had any luck with finding some code that already does this. I'll keep trying, but I would welcome any assistance/insight that you wonderful people on this site can provide.

Comment: Instead of VBA, a pivot table might give you the formatting you are after - have you tried that?

Comment: As@max pointed out, I'd suggest using a Pivot-Table. If you don't know how to insert one, the search or google should help you easily. If you need to apply this formatting in-place (so on you actual data and not just present it in some way on another sheet referencing your data) then you will need to use VBA. For VBA you should first sort your data (maybe with multiple criteria, search function should give you more information) and then loop through your rows and do some workflow like you already posted with your points 1-5. If you need help with realizing these steps in VBA, leave a comment.

Comment: I thought about a pivot table, but they want it formatted like I showed in the second image. I did check though. I think VBA is my best and possibly only option.

I found a tool for KutoolsforExcel that merges duplicate cells like I want, but it does it column by column for the whole worksheet. So all of Column B would merge into one cell. I do know how to set up subroutines in VBA so if you wonderful people could help me come up with a macro that does steps 1-3 and 5, 4 could be a call to Kutools.

Answer (score 0):

So I moved the route into column 1 and got my macro to work with this code:

```
Sheets("Master").Select
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Dim KRng As Range, Kxcell As Range
Dim KxRows As Integer
Dim KeyRng As Range

Set KeyRng = Range("A4:A" & LastRow)
KeyRng.Select
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
KxRows = KeyRng.Rows.Count
        For Each KRng In KeyRng.Columns
            For c = 1 To KxRows - 1
                For d = c + 1 To KxRows
                    If KRng.Cells(c, 1).Value <> KRng.Cells(d, 1).Value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    KeyRng.Parent.Range(KRng.Cells(c, 1), KRng.Cells(d - 1, 1)).Select
    With Selection
    ActiveCell.Resize(d - c, 60).Select
    End With
    Call MergeSameCell
    KeyRng.Parent.Range(KRng.Cells(c, 1), KRng.Cells(d - 1, 1)).Select


    c = d - 1
Next
```

Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Now my question is, how do I get it to select the 60 columns to the right but skip columns 8 through 12? I'll keep researching and see what I can come up with, but I'd welcome a simple or elegant answer.

Comment: I added a bit of code that basically undoes what the first half of the macro does for the range in question, but if there is a way to not select those cells in the first place I'd love to be able to clean this macro up.